# How to reply to "I hope you have enjoyed your holiday"?

Tags: word-in-context, answers

If someone told me:

> I hope you have enjoyed your holiday.

What will be the best way to thank him/her? (in a full sentence)

The followings are what I can think of:

> Thanks for the kind words.
>
> Thanks for your hope(??).

#### EDIT:

Thanks for the answer guys.

One more thing to add is, I cannot directly reply to the original sentence with a "Thank you", because he immediately followed it with another question.

> I hope you have enjoyed your holiday. How is the project going?

Comment: You can still thank for the "holiday" sentiment before continuing your description of the project's progress.

Answer (score 7):

Your first option sounds fine. "Thanks for your hope" doesn't sound right at all. They're also sort of implying the question of "Did you enjoy your holiday?" so you could just answer that question and it would sound good.

> I hope you have enjoyed your holiday.
>
> Thanks, I had a great time!

Comment: Another way you can answer this in the workplace is, "Thanks! It's good to be back, though." That could make an easy transition into talk about the project.

Answer (score 1):

The statement sounds like it is about the holiday you just *had* in the past, in which case you could respond with "Thank you, I did", or "Thank you, I had a lovely holiday"

If instead the statement is about a holiday you *will have* in the future, then "Thanks for the kind words" would be acceptable, though a little bit formal. Alternatively, "Thank you, I hope so too" could be a response, though mostly people just respond with a simple "Thank you", which is a full sentence.